Stacking n amount of objects on top of each other in a specific order using geometry nodes
Stacking n amount of objects on top of each other in a specific order using geometry nodes.
I'm trying to create a group to stack multiple different size objects on top of each other in a specific order.
I can get it to work when the center of the object is at $(0,0,0)$ but other objects like the cone causes issues.
Main node group:

Daisy chained node group following a given order:

Notice: the cube should be at the top of the cone and it's not


To stack several objects on top of each other using node groups, you can use the following setup:

Here I use the maximum value of the bounding box of the lower object as a starting point and add the inverted minimum value of the bounding box of the upper object. Together, this gives the required offset.
It would be even easier to simply subtract the minimum position of the upper object from the maximum position of the lower object:

